# Switch and func pointer, which is faster?

Tags: c++

If I save func pointers to a array, like this

```cpp
typedef int (*p)();
p arr[] = {a, b, c, d};
```

And run it with index:

```cpp
arr[index]();
```

Or I use switch instead of it:

```cpp
switch(index){
    case 1:{
        a();
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        b();
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        c();
        break;
    }
    case 4:{
        d();
        break;
    }
}
```

The first code can call a func in O(1),but the second code can use inline func.Now I want to know, which is faster?

Comment: why "but" ? Why the first cannot inline the call?

Comment: why bother? Use the one that is more readable and maintainable for you

Comment: did you measure? I expect no obervable difference unless `a`, `b`,`c` and `d` take close to 0 time to execute

Comment: BTW, C++ arrays are 0-indexed. so not equivalent code ;)

Comment: Google "optimisation of a switch to a jump table". If the switch labels are consecutive the chances are you have O(1) for the switch case too. But this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard so I wouldn't rely on it. If you need to write performance critical code then you need to use a profiler and check the assembly output for your compilation targets. These days guessing what is fast is difficult. Note your indexing policy differs between the two code snippets.

Comment: also the premise that a switch is much worse than `O(1)` is questionable. `switch` is actually rather efficient

Comment: *"which is faster?"* You have to measure. (except when generated code is identical :-) )

Comment: Trying hot to be patronising here, but a naive question is not necessarily a poor question. Yours is asked well. Have an upvote!

Comment: I've just measured and found that the second code is twice as fast as the first, perhaps because of compiler optimizations such as inlining functions

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets are not equivalent. In addition to the different indexing, the first one does not perform range checking. The second one does not run any of the functions if the index is out of range.

If those differences were resolved, I would not expect to see significant performance differences between the two. The compiler can do all the same tricks you can, and many more. There would be no reason for it to produce code for either of those which wasn't "the best way".